# How to select a specific range of characters and extract it into variable?

Tags: jquery

How can i "filter" a specific range of characters.  For example:

```
Safari  IPv4 ... 0t0  TCP wlan-237-15-16-172:52122->fa-in-f84.1e100.net:https
Dashboard  IPv4 ... 0t0  TCP wlan-237-15-16-172:52122->fa-in-f95.1e100.net:https
```

Every line has the same pattern. I want to select / filter / copy the *ip adress* after "**->**" until "**:https**" into a variable.  When looking at the example above I want to extract these characters:

```
fa-in-f84.1e100.net
fa-in-f95.1e100.net
```

How can I do this?

**And:** What can i do to select all the lines beginning with (for example) "Safari" and then in a second step select the ips…

Comment: with regular expressions

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way :

`var safari = 'TCP wlan-237-15-16-172:52122->fa-in-f84.1e100.net:https';`

`console.log(safari.split('->')[1].split(':https')[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

try this regExp hope this will solve your problem

```
var str = "TCP wlan-237-15-16-172:52122->fa-in-f84.1e100.net:https";
var regexp = /->(.*):/g;
var ip = regexp.exec(str)[1];
console.log(ip);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/huluw/)

UPDATE 1

this will find multiple instance of that pattern

```
var str = "TCP wlan-237-15-16-172:52122->fa-in-f84.1e100.net:https Dashboard  IPv4 ... 0t0  TCP wlan-237-15-16-172:52122->fa-in-f95.1e100.net:https";
var regexp = /(->(.*?):)+?/g;
var resArray = [];
while ((res = regexp.exec(str)) !== null)
{
  console.log("------------------",res);
  resArray.push(res[2]);
}
console.log(resArray);
```

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/huluw/3/edit)

Comment: yea. thank you. now i get the first ip that appears in the strings. how can i collect all of them? know what i mean?

Comment: @iMax See my updated code "update 1" hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
function filter_ip(string) {
    return string.match(/->(.+):/g)[0].replace(/[->:]/g, "");
}

filter_ip("Safari  IPv4 ... 0t0  TCP wlan-237-15-16-172:52122->fa-in-f84.1e100.net:https");
```